# Extracting all rows containing a specific datetime value (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a table which looks like this:

| Entry number | Timestamp | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5758 | 28-06-2018 16:30 | 34 | 63 | 34.2 | 60.9 |
| 5759 | 28-06-2018 17:00 | 33.5 | 58 | 34.9 | 58.4 |
| 5758 | 28-06-2018 16:30 | 34 | 63 | 34.2 | 60.9 |
| 5759 | 28-06-2018 17:00 | 33.5 | 58 | 34.9 | 58.4 |
| 5760 | 28-06-2018 17:30 | 33 | 53 | 35.2 | 58.5 |
| 5761 | 28-06-2018 18:00 | 33 | 63 | 35 | 57.9 |
| 5762 | 28-06-2018 18:30 | 33 | 61 | 34.6 | 58.9 |
| 5763 | 28-06-2018 19:00 | 33 | 59 | 34.1 | 59.4 |
| 5764 | 28-06-2018 19:30 | 28 | 89 | 33.5 | 64.2 |
| 5765 | 28-06-2018 20:00 | 28 | 89 | 33 | 66.1 |
| 5766 | 28-06-2018 20:30 | 28 | 83 | 32.5 | 67 |
| 5767 | 28-06-2018 21:00 | 29 | 89 | 32.2 | 68.4 |

Where `'28-06-2018 16:30'` is under one column. So I have 6 columns:

```
Entry number, Timestamp, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4
```

I want to extract all rows that belong to `'28-06-2018'`, i.e all data pertaining to that day. Since my table is too large I couldn't fit more data, however, the entries under the timestamp range for a couple of months.

Comment: It would be nice to add the table in a minimal working example so people can provide answers faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
t=table([5758;5759],["28-06-2018 16:30";"29-06-2018 16:30"],[34;33.5],'VariableNames',{'Entry number','Timestamp','Value1'})
```

> t =
>
> 2×3 table
>
> ```
> Entry number        Timestamp         Value1
> ____________    __________________    ______
>
>     5758        "28-06-2018 16:30"       34 
>     5759        "29-06-2018 16:30"     33.5
> ```

```
t(contains(t.('Timestamp'),"28-06"),:)
```

> ans =
>
> 1×3 table
>
> ```
> Entry number        Timestamp         Value1
> ____________    __________________    ______
>
>     5758        "28-06-2018 16:30"      34
> ```

Comment: all the values of 28-06-2018 should show up..not just 1

Comment: all the values of 28-06-2018 indeed showed up.  The other line is specifically marked "29-06-2018" to show the difference.